# Make an arrays of links contained in one big string

Tags: image, bash, shell, curl, wget

I have a big string ( a html code from web page).

Now the problem is how to parse the links to images.

I want to make an array of all the links to images in that web page.

I know how to do this i java but I do not know how to do the parse strings and do a string  manipulations in shell. I know there are many tricks and I guess this can be easy done.

in the end I want to get something like this

```
    #!/bin/bash

read BIG_STRING <<< $(curl some_web_page_with_links_to_images.com)

#parse the big string and fill the LINKS variable

    # fill this with the links to image somewhow (.jpg and .png only)
    #after the parsing the LINKS should look like this
    LINKS=("www.asd.com/asd1.jpg" "www.asd.com/asd.jpg" "www.asd.com/asd2123.jpg")


    #I need the parsing and to fill the LINKS variable with the links from the web page

    # get length of an array
    tLen=${#LINKS[@]}


    for (( i=0; i<${tLen}; i++ ));
    do
      echo ${LINKS[$i]}
    done
```

Thanks, for the responses you saved me days of frustrations

Comment: `for url in "${LINKS[@]}"; do echo $url; done`. I don't think you'll gain anything from trying to parse the HTML in `bash`, however.

Answer (score 1):

Why not start with the right tool? Parsing HTML is hard, especially with `sed`. If you have the `mojo` tool from the Mojolicious project you can do this:

```
mojo get http://example.com a attr href
```

And then just check whether each line ends with `jpg`, `png`, or whatever.

Comment: +1 Depending on what you need to do, `mojo` might be a good (because "more correct") specialized solution (even if there's no way to do it "completely correct" in the face of invalid real-world input). On the other hand, regex is well-understood, and noone knows mojo/has it installed...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to offer more than approximations. Let's assume all interesting links are `href=""` attributes, and there's at most one `href` attribute per line (And the links are also one line only, actually I'm not sure if newlines are allowed inside URLs.

Let's assume your sourcefile is called `test.html`.

The following should print all links under these assumptions:

```
sed -n 's/.*\<href="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' test.html
```

To understand how this works, you should know what regular expressions are and have read up a tutorial on sed (particularly how the **s** ubstitute command works)

Comment: but This will find all the links , right ? how to find just the *.jpg and *.png links, namely the links the ends with jpg or png

Comment: @Lukap: Multiple passes: Step 1, find all `href`s; step 2, find the ones you want. Complicating the regex further to achieve this is possible but probably not the best solution. That said, it would be `sed -r -n -e 's/.*\<href="([^"]*(jpg|png))".*/\1/p'`.

Comment: @Lukap: The 2-step solution is like `sed -n 's/.*\<href="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' test.html | grep '\.\(jpg\|png\)$'`